# I am getting this error on using matplotlib

Tags: python, macos, numpy, matplotlib, scipy

I get this error on typing this in python command prompt: import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#1>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 97, in <module>
    _backend_mod, new_figure_manager, draw_if_interactive, _show = pylab_setup()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/__init__.py", line 25, in pylab_setup
    globals(),locals(),[backend_name])
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/backend_macosx.py", line 21, in <module>
    from matplotlib.backends import _macosx
ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/_macosx.so, 2): Library not loaded: /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
  Referenced from: /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/matplotlib-1.3.x-py2.7-macosx-10.8-intel.egg/matplotlib/backends/_macosx.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Can someone suggest me, how i can fix this ? I had installed all the packages with this shell script

https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack

Is there anything that i am missing ? Any additional configuration ?

Comment: When are you getting this error?

Comment: @Mr.Squig on typing "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt" in python command prompt

Comment: I get this error whenever i try to use any functions of matplotlib such as graph etc...

Comment: Do you get an error when you type `import PIL`?

Comment: i dont get any error even if i type import matplotlib

Answer (score 2):

I am seconding andershqst for OSX 10.7.4:

Go to this directory:

```
cd /System/Library/Frameworks
```

Verify that this path exists:

```
ls /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework/Versions/A/CoreText
```

Create this soft link:

```
sudo ln -s /System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework Coretext.framework
```

Then test your fix, [as described in this tutorial](http://jakevdp.github.com/mpl_tutorial/tutorial_pages/tut1.html).

Comment: This worked for me, but the path I had to verify existed was the same I then symlinked, not the one he mentions need to be verified. I.e. it was the suggested path with the `.framework` suffix: `/System/Library/Frameworks/ApplicationServices.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/CoreText.framework`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using ScipySuperpack and solved it the following way.

Open terminal and locate the path to CoreText.framework file

```
sudo find / -name "CoreText.framework"
```

Create a symbolic link from the CoreText file at the located path, to the path in the ImportError

```
sudo ln -s path_located path_where_it_is_missing
```

At this point I got another build error because I run OSX 10.7.5 (10.8 being the one you'll currently get from the ScipySuperpack page) In that case, get the ScipySuperpack from [here](https://github.com/fonnesbeck/ScipySuperpack/tags) and answer 'yes' when prompted 'Are you installing from a repository cloned to this machine (if unsure, answer no)? (y/n)'